# Stuck in model building on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was trying to fit in a random forest tree model, but I keep on encoutering an error where my CV iterator is being told to be empty, which is not the case.

below is the code snippet and the error

```
%%time
rf_val.fit(X_train, y_train)

Fitting 0 folds for each of 32 candidates, totalling 0 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   0 out of   0 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    708                 return results
    709 
--> 710             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    711 
    712         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1149     def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1150         """Search all candidates in param_grid"""
-> 1151         evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
   1152 
   1153 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    690 
    691                 if len(out) < 1:
--> 692                     raise ValueError('No fits were performed. '
    693                                      'Was the CV iterator empty? '
    694                                      'Were there no candidates?')

ValueError: No fits were performed. Was the CV iterator empty? Were there no candidates?
```

I was trying to tune and then fit in a random forest model and was expecting it to be done with time, but I encountered this error, which I can't make anysense of.

Answer (score 1):

In the original sklearn code, under the `fit` function:

```
def evaluate_candidates(candidate_params):
    candidate_params = list(candidate_params)
    n_candidates = len(candidate_params)

    if self.verbose > 0:
        print("Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
              " totalling {2} fits".format(
                  n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits))

    out = parallel(delayed(_fit_and_score)(clone(base_estimator),
                                           X, y,
                                           train=train, test=test,
                                           parameters=parameters,
                                           **fit_and_score_kwargs)
                   for parameters, (train, test)
                   in product(candidate_params,
                              cv.split(X, y, groups)))

    if len(out) < 1:
        raise ValueError('No fits were performed. '
                         'Was the CV iterator empty? '
                         'Were there no candidates?')
```

In your error message:

```
Fitting 0 folds for each of 32 candidates, totalling 0 fits
```

which mean that `n_split = 0`.

`n_split` is defined as:

```
 n_splits = cv.get_n_splits(X, y, groups)
```

In your case, your `group` is set as `None`, so the error may result from your input data `X` and `y`.